# Ruby range: operators in case statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wanted to check if my_number was in a certain range, including the higher Value.

In an IF Statement I'd simply use "x > 100 && x <= 500"

But what should I do in a Ruby case (switch)?

### Using:

```
case my_number
when my_number <= 500
    puts "correct"
end
```

doesn't work.

#### Note:

The standard Range doesn't include the case if my_number is exactly 500, and I don't want to add the second "when", as I would have to write double Content

```
case my_number
# between 100 and 500
when 100..500
    puts "Correct, do something"
when 500
    puts "Correct, do something again"
end
```

Comment: You are wrong. `100..500` does match `500`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should just work like you said. The below `case` construct *includes* the value 500.

```
case my_number
# between 100 and 500
when 100..500
    puts "Correct, do something"
end
```

So:

```
case 500
  when 100..500
    puts "Yep"
end
```

will return `Yep`

Or would you like to perform a separate action if the value is **exactly** 500?

Comment: It did answer my question, and you're absolutely right, still a noob I guess :)

Comment: No worries, glad I could confirm your own answer ;)

Comment: Just for completeness sake: `1..500` includes 500, whereas `1...500` does not include 500.  

Ranges constructed using `..` run from the beginning to the end inclusively. Those created using `...` exclude the end value

Comment: @yossarian, is it possible to use ranges in a case statement as you indicate above with DATE ranges? I want to test if today's date is in certain ranges, and depending on what date range it is in, assign a value to current_week. Thanks

Comment: Here is it with a time range: (Time.now..Time.now+10).cover?(Time.now) see: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Range.html

Answer (score 4):

```
when -Float::INFINITY..0
```

Would do the trick :)

Answer (score 1):

You could just do:

```
(1..500).include? x
```

which is also aliased as `member?`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `case` way to capture `"x > 100 && x <= 500` as desired: a value in a closed range with the start value excluded and the end value included. Also, capturing the ranges before and after that is shown.

```
case my_number
when ..100;         puts '≤100'
when   100..500;    puts '>100 and ≤500'
when        500..;  puts '>500'
end
```

**Explanations:**

- Ranges with one end left out start from `-Infinity` resp. go to `Infinity`. This was [introduced in Ruby 2.6](https://developer.squareup.com/blog/rubys-new-infinite-range-syntax-0/).
- Ranges `x..y` include the end value, ranges `x...y` exclude the end value.
- All ranges include the start value. To create the equivalent of a range without the start value, you can capture the start value in a preceding `when` case. That is how the second `when` case is equivalent to your `"x > 100 && x <= 500` even though `(100..500).include? 100`. Similarly for the third case.