# Multiple line ternary operator - no longer valid.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a piece of code that uses the Ruby Date class to output data within specific date params. At the moment I have a ternary operator that thats says if the current month is greater then or equal to september then output 500_000 and for any other months output 400_000.

Lets say I want to now output 800_000 if the current month october or greater but keep september at 500_000 and everything at 400_00.

My guess is that I'll have to do away with the ternary operator and build a lenghty if else block? Is there a way to do this without making my code too long?

```
september = '01-09-2018'.to_date
october = '01-10-2018'.to_date
    monthly_target_current = start_date_current_week.to_date >= september ? 500_000 : 400_000
    monthly_target_prev_1 = start_date_last_week.to_date >= september ? 500_000 : 400_000
    monthly_target_prev_2 = start_date_week_last_2_weeks.to_date >= september ? 500_000 : 400_000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a method that takes the first value, then uses a switch or if/else block to return the correct value. Ruby case statements can compare to ranges, so you could add months as required.

See this answer for the approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/22700292/771564

Something like this perhaps?

```
def default_date_value(date)
    september = '01-09-2018'.to_date
    october = '01-10-2018'.to_date

    if date >= october
        800_000
    elsif date >= september
        500_000
    else
        400_000
    end
end

monthly_target_current = default_date_value(start_date_current_week)
monthly_target_prev_1  = default_date_value(start_date_last_week)
monthly_target_prev_2  = default_date_value(start_date_week_last_2_weeks)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. And is no help. I'm displaying static figures which are further wrapped inside Ruby functions elsewhere to display these figures accurately.

Comment: They are valid numbers.

Comment: Sorry I misread your question, I've updated my answer accordingly

Comment: @MarcinKołodziej oof, I didn't realise an underscore was a valid number separator